# Android Drawable overlay shape

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, layer-list

I'm trying to create a drawable overlay shape control that will basically have a solid WHITE box at the top and then the remaining segment of the screen will have a gradient from a solid white down to a translucent white.  We use this to lay over a background image to create a solid white area on top and then fading into the a background image towards the bottom.

Using this code it gets basically what I want, except I want a true solid white area under the Company Logo area (sorry I had to blank out the Company Logo and the App Name in the screen shot) with the gradient starting below the solid white.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item>
            <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:shape="rectangle">
                <gradient
                    android:angle="270"
                    android:startColor="#ffffffff"
                    android:centerColor="#00ffffff"
                    android:endColor="#00ffffff"
                    android:centerY="0.6"
                    android:type="linear" />
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:shape="rectangle">
                <gradient
                    android:startColor="#ffffffff"
                    android:centerColor="#ffffffff"
                    android:endColor="#00ffffff"
                    android:centerY="-0.17"
                    android:gradientRadius="100%p"
                    android:type="radial" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </layer-list>
```

Which produces a display similar to this:

[image]

But I really want a more solid white area to be directly under the Company Logo area and then with the gradient starting after that point.  But you can see that the gradient is starting at the top of the screen.

I've tried to do something like the following but it's not working.  Adding the first item in the list does give me a solid area at the top, but for some reason that I'm probably just not understanding is that the top item fills in the entire screen with the solid white color.  I tried moving that first item to the bottom but that still gave me the full solid white screen.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item >
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <size android:height="100dp" />
            <solid android:color="#ffffffff"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="100dp" >
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:angle="270"
                android:startColor="#ffffffff"
                android:centerColor="#00ffffff"
                android:endColor="#00ffffff"
                android:type="linear" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="100dp" >
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#ffffffff"
                android:centerColor="#ffffffff"
                android:endColor="#00ffffff"
                android:centerY="-0.17"
                android:gradientRadius="100%p"
                android:type="radial" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong or give me a better way to do this.

Just for additional information.  The actual image is being applied to the background of the base LinearLayout view.  Then another view is overlayed on top of the base view with this drawable set as the background on it's LinearLayout so it acts as an overlay mask on top of the background image.

I appreciate any help I can get on this.

Comment: Can you add two Linear Layouts children to one Relative Layout parent. Have the top Linear Layout have the background of white, and the bottom one your gradient? I'm not quite sure I'm following correctly.

Comment: Thanks ApolloSoftware, I originally wasn't wanting to do that since this display is used on a couple different screens in my app so I was hoping to do it in a single location like the drawable.  But in taking your idea, I was able to find where I could do this on the base layout view so currently I think I have it working like I need.  If I don't get any better replies or information I'll try to mark your answer as answered.

Comment: Cool i'll add it as an answer. Best of luck with it. I get what you're saying. As you have different portriat/landscape orientations, higher dpis and higher res. layouts, getting it just right on all devices is a pain!, it'll spiral out of control for all types of devices. Thing that sucks about android vs ios, AutoLayout in iOS does a lot for you, it's less customization but much easier to account for lots of diff devices w/ diff sizes! One of the trade offs.

Comment: Hmmm I was thinking. Could you possible put yourCompany logo as a one single PNG with white as the background and use an ImageView sizing it with android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical". I think the vertical orientation could help. Have a relative layout as the parent, then set background color of your LinearLayout child as white. Then in the next LinearLayout child you put rest of your widgets, etc and add your gradient as the child's background. Not sure if this would be any different, but it may be worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

You can add two Linear Layouts children to one Relative Layout parent. Have the top Linear Layout have the background of white, and the bottom one your gradient.